# Why am I occasionally logged in to different domains, or am I?

Tags: discussion, logout, authentication, domain-names

When I log out, I usually get a message saying I will be logged out of these seven domains:

[image]

Notwithstanding the fact I don't know what most of these are, nor consciously visit any of them apart from Stack Exchange and maybe occasionally Stack Overflow, why do I sometimes get this message instead?

[image]

Is it related to my session activity, device (*Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google Chrome app version 102.0.5005.78*) or something else?

Comment: Those are all sites that are part of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: When I tried to log out, it only showed the domain I'm on (so stackexchange.com on most sites and stackoverflow.com on SO). I'm logged into both. I wonder if this is a Chrome security thing.

Comment: Not certain, but I believe it's tied to whether your browser allows the cross-domain cookie that logs you into all sites at once. The dialog populates the list by looking for all site logins tied to your current session Id. If the other sites were logged in on different sessions (which should normally be true if cross-domain cookies are disabled), you'd only see the one domain listed on the logout screen.